# Query Results from Two Tables without a JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 data tables, both with a datetime column however other than this column no other matching columns thus not allowing me to do a JOIN.

I have attempted to do the join on the MonthYear alias and this is not giving me the expected results and it is significantly slower to execute, whilst doing them individually is instant.

However, every month will have data and as I am doing a count by month and ordering I'm thinking a join may not be essential. I've tried a UNION however this provided the results in additional rows when I require it to be in adjacent columns (see desired outcome).

table1:

```
SELECT
LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,[date]),3) + '-' + RIGHT('00' + CAST(YEAR([date]) AS VARCHAR),2) AS 'MonthYear',
COUNT(CASE WHEN responseType = 'positive' THEN 1 END) AS 'Positive',
COUNT(CASE WHEN responseType = 'negative' THEN 1 END) AS 'Negative'
FROM Database.dbo.Response
WHERE [date] BETWEEN '2022/09/01' AND '2022/12/01'
GROUP BY LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,[date]),3) + '-' + RIGHT('00' + CAST(YEAR([date]) AS VARCHAR),2)
ORDER BY MAX([date])
```

table1 results:

```
MonthYear      Positive     Negative
Sep-22         8738         6001
Oct-22         10120        4512
Nov-22         5621         5451
```

table2:

```
SELECT 
LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,[date]),3) + '-' + RIGHT('00' + CAST(YEAR([date]) AS VARCHAR),2) AS 'MonthYear',
COUNT(CASE WHEN Reason = 'Legacy Unsub' THEN 1 END) AS 'Unsub',
COUNT(CASE WHEN Reason = 'Complaint' THEN 1 END) AS 'Complaint'
FROM Database.dbo.Complaint
WHERE [date] BETWEEN '2022/09/01' AND '2022/12/01'
GROUP BY LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, [date]),3) + '-' + RIGHT('00' + CAST(YEAR([date]) AS VARCHAR),2)
ORDER BY MAX([date])
```

table2 results:

```
MonthYear     Unsub    Complaint
Sep-22        541      5
Oct-22        171      0
Nov-22        459      12
```

My desired outcome:

```
MonthYear      Positive     Negative     Unsub     Complaint
Sep-22         8738         6001         541       5
Oct-22         10120        4512         171       0
Nov-22         5621         5451         459       12
```

Comment: you need a full outer JOIN and this will always be slower, you could always "join" them on application side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect the following to give you your expected output and perform not significantly worse than running the two queries individually (although it will ultimately depend on how many different `MonthYear`s you are returning).

```
WITH t1 AS
(
 SELECT
LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,[date]),3) + '-' + RIGHT('00' + CAST(YEAR([date]) AS VARCHAR),2) AS 'MonthYear',
 MAX([date]) AS 'SortOrder',
 COUNT(CASE WHEN responseType = 'positive' THEN 1 END) AS 'Positive',
 COUNT(CASE WHEN responseType = 'negative' THEN 1 END) AS 'Negative'
 FROM Database.dbo.Response
 WHERE [date] BETWEEN '2022/09/01' AND '2022/12/01'
 GROUP BY LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,[date]),3) + '-' + RIGHT('00' + CAST(YEAR([date]) AS VARCHAR),2)
),
t2 AS (
 SELECT 
 LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,[date]),3) + '-' + RIGHT('00' + CAST(YEAR([date]) AS VARCHAR),2) AS 'MonthYear',
 COUNT(CASE WHEN Reason = 'Legacy Unsub' THEN 1 END) AS 'Unsub',
 COUNT(CASE WHEN Reason = 'Complaint' THEN 1 END) AS 'Complaint'
 FROM Database.dbo.Complaint
 WHERE [date] BETWEEN '2022/09/01' AND '2022/12/01'
 GROUP BY LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, [date]),3) + '-' + RIGHT('00' + CAST(YEAR([date]) AS VARCHAR),2)
)
SELECT t1.MonthYear, t1.Positive, t1.Negative, t2.Unsub, t2.Complaint
FROM t1 FULL OUTER JOIN t2
  ON t1.MonthYear = t2.MonthYear
ORDER BY t1.SortOrder
```

This simply joins the results of your two existing queries (as CTEs) on `MonthYear`. I added an additional `SortOrder` column to the first CTE (since we want to sort in date order, not alphabetic order). You said "every month will have data", so perhaps an `INNER JOIN` is sufficient in your case, but the `FULL OUTER JOIN` is probably safer for things like this (where possibly one of the tables doesn't yet have data for a month that the other table has).

Although SQL isn't procedural so there are no guarantees, I expect SQL Server will run your existing queries in about the same time it takes to run them individually, and then matching, say, a few thousand `MonthYear`s should be relatively insignificant.

If this does not have acceptable performance, I would consider adding a computed column `MonthYear` to both tables and indexing that.

Comment: this works great and the performance is perfectly acceptable, thank you.